# Commentator badge progress shows 1/10 before having commenting priviledge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I just received the privilege to post comments on SuperUser (yay!), but before that happened I noticed that the Commentator badge already has a progress of 1/10. I believe this also happened to me on StackOverflow, but I could be misremembering. It does not seem to be happening on any other linked sites.

[image: Commentator badge progress]

Is there an action that counts towards this badge that isn't commenting or is this a bug?

Comment: Probably caching...

Comment: @Mokubai The value has been that way for a day or two and should not have existed in the past since I've never commented.

Comment: You already earned the badge in question.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, on StackOverflow, but not on SuperUser. Does it give you some sort of bonus when you get the badge on a linked site?

Comment: @Worthwelle Badges are absolutely meaningless.  The only exception is a gold badge to a specific tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you have posted at least one comment on [your own answer](https://superuser.com/a/1329135/19943) (that was itself supposedly a comment).

Commenting on your own answers or questions would count towards the total for the commentator badge.

For reference and low rep:

[image]

Comment: Oh jeez. I feel dumb. I totally forgot about that. Thanks!